# Как можно додавать объекты запоминая их значения в цикле

Tags: java, циклы, for

Всем привет, у меня в следующем проблема. Я имею объект `czas1` класса `Czas`. И еще один обьект `czas2`. У меня есть метод `dodaj()`, который правильно работает, и если я пишу `czas1.dodaj(czas2)`, то у меня суммируются эти два обьекта и все класно!

Но что если у меня есть массив из обьектов, например, `Czas[] czas = {czas1, czas2, czas3, czas4}` и я пытаюсь в методе `sumuj()` все эти объекты друг к другу прибавить. Но проблема в том, что каждый раз когда в цикле в методе `sumuj()` я пишу `czas = tab[i].dodaj(tab[i])`, то обьект `czas` у меня не запоминается. И получается так, что в результате я получаю сумму двух последних объектов.

Может кто-то знает как это исправить? Буду рад за подсказки!

Вот код:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Czas czas1 = new Czas(1, 10);
        Czas czas2 = new Czas(2, 10);
        Czas czas3 = new Czas(3, 10);
        Czas czas4 = new Czas(4, 10);

        Czas[] czas = {czas1, czas2, czas3, czas4};
        System.out.print(Czas.sumuj(czas));
    }
}
```

```java
public class Czas {
    private int godz;
    private int minuty;

    public Czas(int godz, int minuty) {
        this.godz = godz;
        this.minuty = minuty;
    }

    public int getGodz() {
        return godz;
    }

    public int getMinuty() {
        return minuty;
    }

    public Czas dodaj(Czas czas) {
        minuty = minuty + czas.getMinuty();
        int temp = minuty / 60;
        godz = godz + czas.getGodz() + temp;
        int temp2 = minuty % 60;
        minuty = temp2;
        return new Czas(godz,minuty);
    }


    static Czas sumuj(Czas[] tab) {
        Czas czas = new Czas(0,0);
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length - 1; i++) {
            czas = tab[i].dodaj(tab[i + 1]);
        }
        return new Czas(czas.godz, czas.minuty);
    }
}
```

Comment: У вас класс `Czas` написан так, что он может мутировать. То есть делать `czas = ...` не имеет особого смысла, а можно просто делать `czas.dodaj()` и сам объект будет изменяться.

Comment: @Vadik спасибо, теперь понял мою проблему! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем новый объект `czas` и к нему додаем все элементы из массива:

```java
static Czas sumuj(Czas[] tab) {
    final Czas czas = new Czas(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        czas.dodaj(tab[i]);
    }
    return czas;
}
```

Можно еще проще:

```java
static Czas sumuj(Czas[] tab) {
    final Czas czas = new Czas(0, 0);
    for (Czas t : tab) {
        czas.dodaj(t);
    }
    return czas;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

К этому коду тонна замечаний. Может лучше сделать так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Time {

    private final int hours;
    private final int minutes;

    public Time(int hours, int minutes) {
        this.hours = hours;
        this.minutes = minutes;
    }

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Time{" + "hours=" + hours + ", minutes=" + minutes + '}';
    }
    
    static Time sumOf (Time ... tab) {        
        int totalMinutes = Arrays.stream(tab).mapToInt(var->var.getHours()*60+var.getMinutes()).sum();
        return new Time(totalMinutes/60, totalMinutes%60);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Time time1 = new Time(1, 10);
        Time time2 = new Time(2, 10);
        Time time3 = new Time(3, 10);
        Time time4 = new Time(4, 10);        
        System.out.print(Time.sumOf(time1, time2, time3, time4));
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделать `final int hours` и `final int minutes` хороший вариант, с немутабельностью всегда иметь дело проще.